# Rename variable in function, how?

Tags: calculus, functions

Suppose I have a function $Tx(\frac{t}{T})$, where $T$ is a constant. If I set $\tau=\frac{t}{T}$, is it correct to write 
$$
Tx(\tau)
$$
or 
$$
\frac{t}{\tau}x(\tau) \quad \text{?}
$$

Comment: your first one is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Both forms are correct but I would prefer $Tx(τ)$. Since $T$ is a constant it means that $t$ and $τ$ are changing in such a way to keep that coefficient constant. So there would be no reason to express $T$ with variables unless you want to do further calculations.

Answer (score 0):

Your second option in fact makes no sense, as it keeps both the old and new variable, which will lead you to various troubles.